# How to save many copies (1000) of .xlsx file from a template.xlsx after editing the template programatically

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx

I have a list of 1000 customers with several amount of data. And I have a .xlsx template for every one of them.

I need to open the template and then go through every item from the list and edit the template value for each one of them. After that I want to save the current file by their name.

Following code is working but it's opening the template every time and it takes too much time to complete the task.

```
foreach (var item in dataList)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Workbook template = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"Location\book1.xlsx");
    Worksheet template_Sheet = template.Worksheets.get_Item(5);

    Range row1 = template_Sheet.Rows.Cells[4, 14];
    row1.Value = item.value;

    template.SaveAs(@"Location\"+ item.name+ ".xlsx", 
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    template.Close();                   
}
```

Is there a faster way so that I can open the template and then go through the list, edit the template and save it as a copy for every element of the list and finally closing the file?

Comment: *Instead* of starting Excel and using Interop, use a library like EPPlus to create a new file based on an existing template, change whatever you want and then save the new file

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos . Do you have any sample for this kind of work ?

Comment: open xml sdk is a great feature for your problem.

Comment: Are you sure you need to close the template at all? You're just changing some values in the range `row1` so why not do it this way(pseudo code): `open workbook template`, `for each item in datalist, modify template, template.SaveAs ...` and finally `template.Close` (Open and close are outside of the loop).

Comment: @lau thank you , EPPlus library is working for me. I'll try your suggestion.